# Performing searches against large dictionaries using php

Tags: php, search, text, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

Currently I am trying to perform text searches against large dictionaries using php or mysql. Until now I haven't found the best way to do that. For example there is a Text:Scan module written in Perl

http://search.cpan.org/~iwoodhead/Text-Scan-0.28/Scan.pm

which is exactly what I need for php. If you are aware of some way to do that in php please share this knowledge with me! :)

Thanks for Your help!

Comment: a db will always be more efficient than a flat file

Comment: Define "large". What is the size of the database you are looking at?

Comment: Do you need to search a string in PHP *or* do you need to perform the search at the database level?

Comment: large means thousands of words, and the size of the corpus will be 10 - 20 pages of plain text or in a db text field. So, it makes no difference for me whether I will search a string or perform db queries. Whatever it takes just I want to work.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understood, what you may need is something like Zend_Search_Lucene. You will get more information from http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.overview.html

Comment: +1 - for anything other than trivial examples, Lucene is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks, definitely I will check this out.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/).

We are using it in one of our projects and it's serving well.

Moreover PHP has [PECL extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sphinx.php) for it.

Comment: It's not built in, it's a `pecl` extension.

Comment: Thanks, I will looked into it, and hopped that it supports to search for thousands of words in a text at ones.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has in-built support for full-text indexing and search:
[here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match). This might be what you are looking for

Comment: Yes, but this feature search one word at a time. You can add more with the OR connector but this is a very limited. What I want is to be able to search for thousands of words in a text at ones.